# Cleaner way to iterate over optional attributes in an object list?

Tags: java, json, java-8, iterator

I have a list of item objects

```
“Items”: [
      {
        "Identifier": {
          “Identity”: {
            “ID”: “123”,
            “Country” : “Japan”
          }
        },
        “Color”: “Red”,
        “Size”: {
          "Units": “cm”,
          "value": 140
        }
      },
      {
        "Identifier": {
          “Identity”: {
            “ID”: “345”,
            “Country” : “Russia”
          }
        },
        “Weight”: “90 lb”,
        “Height” : “170 cm”
      }]
```

Item class looks like this

```
public class Item {

//properties 
private IdentifierType Identifier = null;
private String Color = null;
private DimensionType Dimensions = null;
private String Weight = null;
private String Height = null;

With corresponding getter and setters for the above attributes

}
```

I am trying to read the item objects from the item list and create a map of <ID, List>
Where property object is like

```
Public class property {
     String propertyName
     String propertyValue
}
```

Eg.

```
{
   123,  [ {“propertyName” : “Color”, “propertyValue”: “Red”}, {“propertyName” : size, “propertyValue”: “140 cm”}],
   345, [ {“propertyName” : “Weight”, “propertyValue”: “90 lb”}, {“propertyName” : Height, “propertyValue”: “170 cm”}]
}
```

I am able to iterate the list to fetch the IDs for the item objects but I am not able to create the list of property objects without checking if each property is null or not.
In order to populate the property list I will have to do a get for all the properties in the item object and create property objects for the ones that are not null. (Modifying the item class is not an option)

I am trying to find a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Would using a json serialization library and enabling "only non empty fields" work? The other option is deserialise them all as untyped `Map<String, Object>` which will deserialize *any* json object - the `Object` will be another `Map<String, Object>` to any depth if there's nesting.

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 1):

Let your data:

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "Identifier": {
        "Identity": {
          "ID": "123",
          "Country": "Japan"
        }
      },
      "Color": "Red",
      "Size": {
        "Units": "cm",
        "value": 140
      }
    },
    {
      "Identifier": {
        "Identity": {
          "ID": "345",
          "Country": "Russia"
        }
      },
      "Weight": "90 lb",
      "Height": "170 cm"
    }
  ]
}
```

I suggest creating a proper data structure first that fits your needs (eg):

```
static class Identity {
    public String ID;
    public String Country;
}

static class Identifier {
    public Identity Identity;
}

static class Size {
    public String Units;
    public Integer value;
}

static class Item {
    public Identifier Identifier;
    public String Color;
    public Size Size;
    public String Height;
    public String Weight;
}

static class Data {
    public List<Item> Items;
}
```

then you can use a robust way to parse from your data file (stream, string, ...)

```
Data data = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File("test.json"), Data.class);
```

now, you can transform as you wish, to traverse all properties and collect the non nullable, we define the `Property` class

```
static class Property {
    public String name;
    public String value;

    public Property(String name, String value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // make a property from a nullable value
    public static Optional<Property> from(String name, Object value) {
        return ofNullable(value).map(v -> new Property(name, v.toString()));
    }
}
```

the `from` method is a helper to avoid `if`.

To collect the properties we must to traverse all of them:

```
// flatMap to properties
List<Property> properties = data
        .Items.stream()                         // get items as stream
        .flatMap(item ->                        // flat map all their properties you want
                Stream.of(                      // collect all of them
                    ofNullable(item.Identifier)             // if not null
                        .map(id -> id.Identity)             // if not null
                        .map(id -> Stream.of(
                                from("ID", id.ID),
                                from("Country", id.Country)
                        ))
                        .orElse(Stream.empty()),
                    ofNullable(item.Size)                   // if not null
                            .map(size -> Stream.of(
                                    from("Units", size.Units),
                                    from("value", size.value)
                            ))
                            .orElse(Stream.empty()),
                    Stream.of(from("Color", item.Color)),
                    Stream.of(from("Height", item.Height)),
                    Stream.of(from("Weight", item.Weight))
                )
                .flatMap(x -> x)                // flat map nested property lists
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)    // only presents
                .map(Optional::get)
        )
        .collect(toList());
```

with output:

```
ID: 123
Country: Japan
Units: cm
value: 140
Color: Red
ID: 345
Country: Russia
Height: 170 cm
Weight: 90 lb
```

The `ID` is not mandatory, but we can group using a default:

```
Map<String, List<Property>> properties = data
        .Items.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(
                item -> ofNullable(item.Identifier).map(id -> id.Identity).map(id -> id.ID).orElse("no-id"),
                collectingAndThen(toList(), xs -> xs
                .stream()
                ...(same aggregation)...
```

now, printing the map is

```
// print all
properties.forEach((id, values) -> {
    System.out.printf("== %s === %n", id);
    values.forEach(v -> System.out.printf("  %s: %s%n", v.name, v.value));
});
```

with output

```
== 123 === 
  ID: 123
  Country: Japan
  Units: cm
  value: 140
  Color: Red
== 345 === 
  ID: 345
  Country: Russia
  Height: 170 cm
  Weight: 90 lb
```

You have a specific **contract** (the classes you have defined), although you should write more code lines I recommend the previous solution (map each specific type one by one),your solution will be much more robust.

Anyway, if you wish this solution works for any class hierarchy, you can use reflection, simply replacing all the previous `flatMap` lambda with:

```
public static Stream<Property> from(Object object) {
    if (object == null)
        return Stream.empty();
    List<Stream<Property>> rs = new ArrayList<>();
    Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();
    for (Field field : clazz.getFields())
        if (field.getType() == String.class || field.getType() == Integer.class)
            rs.add(from(field.getName(), field.get(object)).map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty()));
        else
            rs.add(from(field.get(object)));
    return rs.stream().flatMap(x -> x);
}
```

the new replaced aggregation is

```
collectingAndThen(toList(), xs -> xs
        .stream()
        .flatMap(Property::from)
        .collect(toList()))
```

but you must to code special cases like what do you mean by *"final data"* (`Integer`, `String`, ... what else?) and other special (and possible non standard) structures like `List<>`, `Stream<>`, ... and you will enter in the world of Lombok, Jackson, ...

(The new output using reflection is)

```
== 123 === 
  ID: 123
  Country: Japan
  Color: Red
  Units: cm
  value: 140
== 345 === 
  ID: 345
  Country: Russia
  Height: 170 cm
  Weight: 90 lb
```

Comment: Thanks @josejuan I was actually trying to figure out if its possible to create the map " without traversing all properties and collecting the non nullables"

Comment: @nfornicole It is usually much better to write a lot of very simple code than little complex code. If you know the structure, it is better to write specific code. Anyway, I have extended the solution with a generic version.

Comment: how have you defined the from(string, object) method ?

Comment: It's there `public static Optional<Property> from(String name, Object value) {` and `public static Stream<Property> from(Object object) {`...